# Nilpotent endomorphism Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

For a finite dimensional Vectorspace V and a nilpotent Endomorphism $ \phi$ with index of nilpotency k

> $Kernel(\phi^0) \subsetneq Kernel(\phi^1) \subsetneq Kernel(\phi^2) \subsetneq .... \subsetneq Kernel(\phi^k)$

holds. Could someone give an intuition as to why the not-equal part must hold, i.e. what contradiction a violation of this condition would lead to ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thanks for the answer. k is indeed the nilpotency index. Could you expand on how to see that $ker(\phi^i)=ker(\phi^{i+1}) \implies ker(\phi^{i+1}))=ker(\phi^{i+2})) $

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, there will be a sufficiently large $k$ such that $\ker(\phi^{k}) = \ker(\phi^{k + 1})$ at which point all of the subsequent inclusions become $=$. ($k = \dim V$ works for example).